# Using Route instead of RoutePrefix at controller level in .net web api attribute routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, attributerouting

If I decorate this web api controller with the Route attribute I can hit the method

```
[Route("api/v{version}/bank-accounts")]
public class BankAccountsController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetBankAccounts()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

But if I use RoutePrefix instead I can't make it work unless at the same time I use Route("")

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v{version}/bank-accounts")]
public class BankAccountsController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetBankAccounts()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Is this intended, or I'm messing things?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75998447/7186739

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Right, this is an expected behavior... `RoutePrefix` attribute by itself doesn't add any routes to the route table where as `Route` attributes do...

Answer (score 7):

You are missing it... The route prefix, is just that, a prefix. You should move part of the path template to the route attribute. Like this.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v{version}")]
public class BankAccountsController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("bank-accounts")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetBankAccounts(string version)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```