# No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI in MVC application

Tags: model-view-controller

**WebApiConfig.cs**

public static class WebApiConfig

```
{

    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

**Global.aspx**

```
 protected void Application_Start()
 {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
```

**Api Controller**

```
 [RoutePrefix("api/buyinsurance")]
    public class buyinsuranceapi : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/<controller>
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
}
```

**Calling API Url**

Error image

[image: error image]

I have added API controller in the existing MVC application that time I have faced an issue.
please if anyone has an idea give me suggestion

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36557911/routeprefix-vs-route

Comment: Thanks for giving an answer, In my code, I think to arise problems related to https so not calling API controller. please anyone has an idea please give me suggestion about https