# Swagger error Ambiguous HTTP method for action Actions require explicit HttpMethod binding

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

I am trying to generate swagger docs for my API.  Every time I navigate to the swagger docs I get this error:

> Ambiguous HTTP method for action - [ControllerName]Controller.DownloadFile. Actions require an explicit HttpMethod binding for Swagger/OpenAPI 3.0

Here is the "offending" code it is complaining about in my controller:

```
    using Models;
using Utilities;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class LibrarianController : ControllerBase
    {
        private IFileUploadUtilties fileUtilities;
        private IConfiguration config;
        private ApiContext context;
        private IFileRetrieval fileRetrieval;
        public LibrarianController(IFileUploadUtilties utilities, IConfiguration config, FinwiseApiContext context, IFileRetrieval fileRetrieval)
        {
            fileUtilities = utilities;
            this.config = config;
            this.context = context;
            this.fileRetrieval = fileRetrieval;
        }

       [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok("Ok");
        }

        // GET api/<LibrarianController>/5
        [HttpGet("/api/[controller]/{Id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                return Ok(await fileRetrieval.GetFileForPartnerItemById(id));
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            
        }
        [HttpGet ("/api/[controller]/[action]/{fileId}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadFile(int fileId)
        {
            if (fileId == 0)
                return Content("File Id missing");

            var fileDownload = await fileRetrieval.GetFileForPartnerItemById(fileId);
            var contentType = await fileUtilities.GetFileType(Path.GetExtension(fileDownload.NewFileName));

            var path = Path.Combine(config.GetSection("StoredFilePath").Value, fileDownload.NewFileName);

            var memory = new MemoryStream();
            using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
            {
                await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
            }
            memory.Position = 0;
            return File(memory, contentType, Path.GetFileName(path));
        }

        [HttpGet("api/[controller]/{PartnerId}/{ItemId}")]
        public async Task<List<FileUploads>> GetFiles(string PartnerId, string ItemId)
        {
            var getFiles =  await fileRetrieval.GetAllFilesForPartnerItem(PartnerId, ItemId);
            return getFiles;
        }
        
        
        // POST api/<LibrarianController>
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromForm] FileInformation fileInfo)
        {
            int newFileVersion = 1;

            if (fileInfo == null || fileInfo.Files == null || fileInfo.Files.Count == 0)
                return BadRequest("File(s) not found");

            try
            {
                foreach (var locFile in fileInfo.Files)
                {
                    //check for file extension, if not there, return an error
                    var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(locFile.FileName);
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileExtension))
                        return BadRequest("Files must include file extension");


                    var valid = await fileUtilities.IsFileValid(locFile);

                    var newFileName = string.Concat(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),valid.fileExtension);

                    var newFileLocation = Path.Combine(config.GetSection("StoredFilePath").Value, newFileName);
                   

                    if (!valid.FileExtensionFound)
                    {
                        return BadRequest($"Error {valid.FileExtensionFoundError}");
                    }
                    if (!valid.FileSizeAllowed)
                    {
                        return BadRequest($"Error: {valid.FileSizeAllowedError}");
                    }


                    //check for an existing file in the database.  If there is one, increment the file version before the save
                    var currentFile = await fileUtilities.FileExists(fileInfo, locFile);

                    if (currentFile != null)
                    {
                        newFileVersion = currentFile.Version + 1;
                    }
              
                    //save to the file system
                    using (var stream = new FileStream(newFileLocation, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                    {
                        await locFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
                    }

                    //save to the db.  Check to see if the file exists first.  If it does, do an insert, if not, return an error
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(newFileLocation))
                    {
                        FileUploads upload = new FileUploads
                        {
                            EntityId = fileInfo.EntityId,
                            FileName = locFile.FileName,
                            ItemId = fileInfo.ItemId.ToString(),
                            NewFileName = newFileName,
                            ValidFile = true,
                            Version = newFileVersion
                        };
                        context.FileUploads.Add(upload);
                        context.SaveChanges();
                        //TODO: fire event the file has been saved provide Id key to find the record
                        //upload.Id;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return BadRequest("Error: File Could not be saved");
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest("Failure to upload files.");
            }
            return Ok("File Uploaded");
        }

        // PUT api/<LibrarianController>/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/<LibrarianController>/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

This end point works fine when I test it.  I set the route and it is decorated with the HTTP so I don't understand what it is complaining about.  I looked around for a solution, but from what I could see it is stating there is a public method not decorated in the controller, however there are not undecorated methods in this controller.  What is the problem here?  If I remove the routing info from the HttpGet the method is not reachable, so I need to have both the Route and the HttpGet decorators to reach this method (unless I did that wrong too).  How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you include the full controller? Is there another Method named `DownloadFile` within that controller? Also curious why you included the `[Route]` annotation when you already specified the route in the `[HttpGet]` annotation.

Comment: This is the only method.  I'll include the whole controller.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Why Ambiguous

Here is your routing for `DownloadFile()`:

```cs
[HttpGet ("/api/[controller]/[action]/{fileId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadFile(int fileId)
```

And this is the one for `GetFiles()`:

```cs
[HttpGet("api/[controller]/{PartnerId}/{ItemId}")]
public async Task<List<FileUploads>> GetFiles(string PartnerId, string ItemId)
```

Consider a GET request `/api/Librarian/DownloadFile/62959061`. This url fits BOTH actions:

- For `DownloadFile()`, *DownloadFile* is `[action]` and *62959061* is `fileId`.
- For `GetFiles()`, *DownloadFile* is `PartnerId` and *62959061* is `ItemId`. (.NET will treat *62959061* as a string when doing model binding.)

That's why you have the *Ambiguous* error.

### Suggestions

Assign each action a *unique* name and a *predictable* route.

#### 1. Method name duplication

Instead of having these:

```cs
public IActionResult Get() { /*...*/ }
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id) { /*...*/ }
```

Rename one of the method to avoid same method name:

```cs
public IActionResult Get() { /*...*/ }
public async Task<IActionResult> GetById(int id) { /*...*/ }
```

#### 2. Defining a unique route

Form the controller you defined, I suggest you to use `[RoutePrefix]` at controller level and use `[Route]` or `[Http{Method}]` at action level. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36557911/routeprefix-vs-route) is the related discussion on what they are.

Defining the route using the same pattern can avoid creating ambiguous route accidentally. Below is my attempt to redefine the routings:

```cs
[RoutePrefix("api/[controller]")] // api/Librarian
[ApiController]
public class LibrarianController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("")] // GET api/Librarian/
    public IActionResult Get() { /*...*/ }

    [HttpGet("{Id}")] // GET api/Librarian/62959061
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetById(int id) { /*...*/ }

    [HttpGet("download/{fileId}")] // GET api/Librarian/download/62959061
    public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadFile(int fileId) { /*...*/ }

    [HttpGet("getfiles/{PartnerId}/{ItemId}")] // GET api/Librarian/getfiles/partnerid/itemid
    public async Task<List<FileUploads>> GetFiles(string PartnerId, string ItemId) { /*...*/ }

    [HttpPost("")] // POST api/Librarian/
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromForm] FileInformation fileInfo) { /*...*/ }

    [HttpPut("{id}")] // PUT api/Librarian/62959061
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody] string value) { /*...*/ }

    [HttpDelete("{id}")] // DELETE api/Librarian/62959061
    public void Delete(int id) { /*...*/ }
}
```

By adding a path for `DownloadFile()` and `GetFiles()` the app should be able to identify the route correctly as the app knows all routes with `/download` must go to `DownloadFile()` and all routes with `/getfiles` must go to `GetFiles()`.

Comment: Thanks this fixed it.  What was killing me is on the decorators I was putting the paths in as /download/{fileId} instead of download/{fileId}.  That forward slash was messing things up a lot so that's why I was doing the route decorators.  Again, thanks.

Answer (score 28):

I solved my problem by including the `[NonAction]` signature in the header of functions that were not endpoints

Example

```
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class RequestController : ControllerBase {

    [NonAction]
    public ObjectResult SetError( Exception e)
    {
        return StatusCode(500, e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. Adding [NonAction] to my helper function which is not the endpoint

Comment: Same problem I have after multiple tries. I am not able to fix this but finally, this [NonAction] worked!!

Answer (score 3):

My two cents.

I have a few endpoints, because of which I was getting errors in similar lines.

> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGeneratorException: Ambiguous HTTP method for action - BuberDinner.Api.Controllers.ErrorsController.Error (BuberDinner.Api). Actions require an explicit HttpMethod binding for Swagger/OpenAPI 3.0

I had to the following tweaks to get over this.

1. When my end point is the following

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace BuberDinner.Api.Controllers;

public class ErrorsController : ControllerBase
{
    [Route("error")]
    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        var exception = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>()?.Error;
        return Problem();
    }
}
```

I added the following attribute to fix that.

```
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
```

So the api now looks as follows.

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace BuberDinner.Api.Controllers;

[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
public class ErrorsController : ControllerBase
{
    [Route("error")]
    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        var exception = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>()?.Error;
        // return Problem(title: exception?.Message, statusCode: 400);
        return Problem();
    }
}
```

2. And in another 'login' endpoint,

```cs
using BuberDinner.Api.Filters;
using BuberDinner.Application.Services.Authentication;
using BuberDinner.Contracts.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace BuberDinner.Api.Controllers;

[ApiController]
[Route("auth")]
public class AuthenticationController : ControllerBase
{
  private readonly IAuthenticationService _authenticationService;
  public AuthenticationController(IAuthenticationService authenticationService)
  {
    _authenticationService = authenticationService;
  }

    [Route("login")]
    public IActionResult Login(LoginRequest request)
    {
        var authenticationResult = _authenticationService.Login(request.Email,
                                                                request.Password);

        var response = new AuthenticationResponse(
            authenticationResult.User.Id,
            authenticationResult.User.FirstName,
            authenticationResult.User.LastName,
            authenticationResult.User.Email,
            authenticationResult.Token);
            
        return Ok(response);
    }    
}
```

I replaced the [Route("login")] with [HttpPost("login")]

Finally the swagger UI shows up now.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve it using the following attribute: `[HttpGet, ActionName ("GetId")]`. I named the method using `ActionName()`.