# RoutePrefix Ignored

Tags: c#, api

Someone at my company had the issue where this happened:

```
[RoutePrefix("R2D2")]
public class R2D2RobotController {...}
```

Valid Route (200 Success):

```
api/R2D2Robot
```

Invalid Route (404 error):

```
api/R2D2
```

As far as I was aware the [RoutePrefix] was an valid attribute to use.
I'm not sure what is causing it, but my thoughts are that there is a confugration option that either builds the url from the controller name, or from the [Route] attribute

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36557911/routeprefix-vs-route

Comment: @stuartd, different question. The API is setup as the one that works with the exception of the controller name.